# Determine IP address of an alias not in HOSTS file?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003, hosts-file

We have an application that references the database connection via a common alias, let's say `datatier`, and futher that alias is generally stored in the HOSTS file. However, it's not in the HOSTS file on this server I'm working with.

Two questions:

1. Where else could the alias be stored?
2. Is there a way I can determine the IP anyway?

P.S. -- I've tried running an `nslookup datatier` to determine the IP address but that didn't work.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `nslookup` for things like `hosts` file entries. However, first idea coming to my mind is starting a simple `ping`: `ping datatier`

Even if the host doesn't answer or you cancel using Ctrl+C, it should print the IP address of the host as it's been resolved/determined by whatever means.

Comment: OK, so that got me the IP address ... where else could that alias be stored?

Comment: It might be cached by Windows and possibly be returned by a non-standard DNS (i.e. not the ones set as the default DNS in your TCP/IP configuration). By default `nslookup` will only query the standard DNS servers. You could try clearing the cache using `ipconfig /flushdns`, then try pinging again.

Comment: OK, well I'll go down that road and see what I find -- however, you got me exactly what I needed, the IP address, thanks for your help Mario!

Answer (score 1):

If nslookup isn't providing the answer, and it isn't in the hosts file, then `netbios` is the most likely resolution protocol being used given it is Windows.

Try `nbtstat -a datatier`